# Как сделать интерактивную карту с маршрутами на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, openstreetmap, folium

Мне нужно сделать карту, я знаю про folium и osmnx, но мне нужно, чтобы карта могла и офлайн работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здраствуйте! Попробуйте [Planet.osm](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/RU:Planet.osm)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)